# Como generar un script INSERT automático a una tabla

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, trigger, jobs

Recién empiezo con SQLServer, no se si sea con un job, trigger o un procedure, en fin lo que necesito que me puedan apoyar es en realizar lo siguiente, en una base de datos donde almaceno el registro de algunos requerimientos, que se encuentran asociados a un estado donde estos pueden ser Terminado o Cerrado, los requerimientos que se encuentran en estado Terminado después de una semana (7 días exactamente) deberán cambiar de estado automáticamente a Cerrado, pero adicional a eso necesito que realice el INSERT (automático) de ese registro que se hizo, quiere decir, que todos los datos de la fila se insertan igual y lo único que cambia es la columna que corresponde a estado, que en este caso seria Terminado.

La siguiente es la consulta con la cual obtengo los registros de los requerimientos mayor a 7 días con el estado Terminado.

```
SELECT TK_DT_RECORDS.*
FROM TK_HD_TICKETS AS TICKETS
INNER JOIN TK_DT_RECORDS ON TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID
WHERE TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_DT_RECORDS_ID = (SELECT MAX (TK_DT_RECORDS_ID) FROM TK_DT_RECORDS 
WHERE TICKETS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_HD_TICKETS_ID )
AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.TK_CT_STATUS_ID = 'TMN') 
AND (TK_DT_RECORDS.ACTIVITY_DATE < DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()));
```

Hasta ahi no se como realizar el INSERT automático, a dicha tabla.

`TK_CT_STATUS_ID` Corresponde al Identificador del estado TMN para Terminado, CDO para Cerrado

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es "algo" que revise con cierta frecuencia (1 hora, 1 día, ...) los trabajos (o lo que sea) activos desde hace una semana que no han cambiado de estado y pasarlos a estado Terminado, haciendo un nuevo `insert` en una tabla.

Lo más óptimo es realizar un procedimiento almacenado que ejecute tu consulta, detectando los casos existentes y que realice las acciones pertinentes (`updates`, `inserts`).

Este procedimiento almacenado deberá ejecutarse con la frecuencia que tu indiques. Lo puedes hacer de forma sencilla mediante un `job` de SQL Server. Para ello debes tener el SQL Server Agent ejecutándose y allí crear un nuevo trabajo (job) definiendo como único paso la ejecución del procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: Tienes idea de como hacer el stored procedure con esa query ?